# Eclipse linker options

Tags: gcc, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to get Eclipse work as my IDE for ARM developing.

I'm trying to set the appropiate linker options, but somehow there are some errors I cannot get rid of.

My linker options:

```
    -nostartfiles ­TC:\Users\Péter\workspace\AndOr_0x01/ldscript/STM32F103RB_FLASH.ld ­Wl,­­gc­sections
 ­mcpu=cortex­m3 ­mthumb ­Wl,­Map=AndOr_0x01.map ­­specs=nosys.specs ­­specs=nano.specs
```

Errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1  AndOr_0x01          C/C++ Problem
make: *** [src/system_stm32f10x.o] Error 1  AndOr_0x01          C/C++ Problem
```